# Is $\mathbb{R}^{a\text{ x } a}$ equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^{a^2}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In my linear algebra course I was given $\mathbb{R}^{a\text{ x }a}  $ as "the set of all $a$ by $a$ matrices".

While $\mathbb{R}^{a^2}$ was "the set of vectors with $a^2$ coordinates".

Ex $\mathbb{R}^{2\text{ x }2}$ contains 2 by 2 matrices while $\mathbb{R}^4$ contains 4-coordinate vectors.

But in set theory sets like these were described as a cartesian product, and it confused me.

Is $\mathbb{R}^{a\text{ x } a}$ equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^{a^2}$?

Comment: There is a bijection between the two sets.  These are just shorthand notations for sets to be discussed.  They mean whatever the author defines them to mean.

Comment: It's worth noting that $\mathbb R^{a^2}$ would generally be considered as a vector space, where $\mathbb R^{a\times a}$ might be considered as a *ring* of matrices - that is, it has a multiplicative structure. If you drop the multiplicative structure (or endow $\mathbb R^{a^2}$ with suitable ring structure), then they're identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent in the sense that they are isomorphic as vector spaces, as any two finite-dimensional vector spaces with the same dimension are isomorphic. That is, there is a bijection $f:\mathbb R^{a\times a}\to\mathbb R^{a^2}$ which is also a linear map (i.e. $f(ax+by)=af(x)+bf(y)$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb R^{a\times a}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb R$).

They are, however, different sets. An $a\times a$ matrix is a distinct object from a $a^2$-dimensional vector.